# how to control global variable reference while printing multiple customer's information?

Tags: livecycle

i have multiple customers information in a xml file while previewing that xml in Adobe LiveCycle Designer in all pages it was showing global variable reference ,i want to see each customer information in separate page.

Ex: i have 3 customers information in a xml file and customer name is a global variable 
1.a
2.b
3.c

while previewing the xml in xdp template customer name is over riding in all pages that is customer "a".

can any one plz help on this.

Comment: is this question about Adobe LiveCycle Designer?, or about something else